# tvOS UIPress gestures not being recognized in subclass of SKScene

Tags: swift, tvos

I am trying to respond to a press in a subclass of SKScene. I can override the responder pressesEnded inside of my ViewController just fine, but when I move my pressesEnded override into my SKScene sub class I no longer receive any calls.

Below is my pressesEnabled override, which works as intended inside of ViewController

```
override func pressesEnded(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    print("press")
}
```

Anybody know how to receive button presses inside of a SKScene?

Comment: Is the SKScene first responder?

Comment: It is not, but it may be worth noting that all touch events are being hit.

Comment: Does it work if you make it first responder? Can you set a breakpoint inside the touch event handlers to see the stack trace / how they're getting forwarded to the scene?

Comment: I think it should work but try tapGestureRecognizer by setting allowedPressTypes to that button type, and see if its working.

Comment: I also tried the tapGestureRecognizer, but it seemed to be the same story. I will paste in the code for that shortly.

I did attempt to make it first responder, but to no avail. I read the documentation quite a bit, and I got the idea that you could not force first responders due to the new focus hierarchy. My interpretation could be incorrect, but that is where I am at with that. I will also post the touch event stacktrace later today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to forward your press events from your ViewController to the SKScene, like so...

```
override func pressesBegan(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {   
  gameScene.pressesBegan(presses, withEvent: event)
}

override func pressesEnded(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
  gameScene.pressesEnded(presses, withEvent: event)
}
```

Then in gameScene (SKScene) do something like:

```
override func pressesBegan(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
  for press in presses {
    switch press.type {
    case .UpArrow:
      print("Up Arrow")
    case .DownArrow:
      print("Down arrow")
    case .LeftArrow:
      print("Left arrow")
    case .RightArrow:
      print("Right arrow")
    case .Select:
      print("Select")
    case .Menu:
      print("Menu")
    case .PlayPause:
      print("Play/Pause")
    }
  }
}

override func pressesEnded(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
  print("Presses Ended.")
}
```

The "Arrow" presses are sent when the user taps the edges of the touchpad, but aren't recognized in the simulator. "Select" is sent when the center of the touchpad is tapped.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is what I am going to end up doing for the time being, but if the associated presses functions are contained within the super class SKScene then isn't that an indication that the associated functions are being used somewhere internally inside of tvOS?

Answer (score 1):

Use `pressesBegan` to map a physical button (Menu, PlayPause), and `pressesBegan` or `pressesEnded` for the trackpad of the Apple TV Remote (left, right, etc).
If you press on a "button" of the trackpad and move to another location and release, the method `pressesEnded` is not called, you can't do this with a physical button.

**Presses Began:**

```
override func pressesBegan(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
        print("Press began")
        for item in presses {
            if item.type == .PlayPause {
                    print("PlayPause")
            }
        }
}
```

**Presses Ended:**

```
override func pressesEnded(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
        print("Press Ended")
        for item in presses {
            if item.type == .RightArrow {
                print("Right Arrow")
            }
        }
    }
```